# Db2 on OpenShift

Tags: db2, openshift

I am new to OpenShift and trying to deploy IBM Db2 on OCP.
following https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-db2
but as soon as I am deploying the pods, the pods are forever in pending state and show the error as:

```
Events:

  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  8s (x65 over 95m)  default-scheduler  0/5 nodes are available: 5 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

even if I mark dedicated as false(parameter mentioned in the github link under Configuration section of README.md) or if I label the nodes(3 master 2 worker) as icp4data=icp4data I get the same error.

The output of one of the pods (8 in total) to "oc get po -o yaml db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job-8k7h8":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/scc: db2oltp-scc
    productID: 5737-K75
    productName: Db2 Community Edition
    productVersion: 11.5.4.0
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-09T12:27:00Z"
  generateName: db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job-
  labels:
    app: db2u-release-2
    chart: ibm-db2
    controller-uid: 4631c618-9904-4978-b5c9-43edd827ce9e
    heritage: Tiller
    icpdsupport/app: db2u-release-2
    icpdsupport/serviceInstanceId: db2u-relea-ibm-db2
    job-name: db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job
    release: db2u-release-2
  name: db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job-8k7h8
  namespace: db2-spm
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Job
    name: db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job
    uid: 4631c618-9904-4978-b5c9-43edd827ce9e
  resourceVersion: "2173118"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/db2-spm/pods/db2u-release-2-db2u-engn-update-job-8k7h8
  uid: 09ef3921-63e0-4761-83fe-8ad5986c59d4
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - unknown
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - "DETERMINATION_FILE=/mnt/blumeta0/nodeslist\nCAT_NODE=$(head -1 $DETERMINATION_FILE)\ncmd=\"\"\nupdt_upgrd_opt=\"-all\"\nhadr_enabled=\"false\"\nRC=0\n\nkubectl
      exec -it -n db2-spm ${CAT_NODE?} -- bash -c '[[ -f /mnt/blumeta0/vrmf/change.out
      ]] || exit 0; exit $(cat /mnt/blumeta0/vrmf/change.out)' 2>/dev/null\nvrmf_chk=$?\necho
      \"VRMF check status bit: ${vrmf_chk}\"\n\n# If HADR is enabled dont run the
      DB update/upgrade scripts. This will be handled\n# by external mechanics to
      work around rolling updates.\nkubectl exec -it -n db2-spm ${CAT_NODE?} -- bash
      -c 'grep -qE \"^HADR_ENABLED.*true\" /mnt/blumeta0/configmap/hadr/*' 2>/dev/null\n[[
      $? -eq 0 ]] && hadr_enabled=\"true\"\n[[ \"${hadr_enabled}\" == \"true\" ]]
      && updt_upgrd_opt=\"-inst\"\n\n# Check VRMF change bit and execute Db2 update
      or upgrade process\nif [[ $vrmf_chk -ne 0 ]]; then\n    if [[ $vrmf_chk -eq
      1 ]]; then\n        echo \"Running the Db2 engine update script ...\"\n        cmd=\"su
      - db2inst1 -c '/db2u/scripts/db2u_update.sh ${updt_upgrd_opt}'\"\n    elif [[
      $vrmf_chk -eq 2 ]]; then\n        echo \"Running the Db2 engine upgrade script
      ...\"\n        cmd=\"su - db2inst1 -c '/db2u/scripts/db2u_upgrade.sh ${updt_upgrd_opt}'\"\n
      \   fi\n    [[ -n \"$cmd\" ]] && kubectl exec -it -n db2-spm ${CAT_NODE?} --
      bash -c \"$cmd\"\n    RC=$?\n    [[ $RC -ne 0 ]] && exit $RC\n\n    # If HADR
      is enabled, dont start Woliverine HA\n    [[ \"${hadr_enabled}\" == \"true\"
      ]] && exit $RC\n\n    # For all other Db2 engine update/upgrade scenarios, start
      Woliverine HA on all Db2U PODs now\n    echo \"Starting Wolverine HA ...\"\n
      \   cmd=\"source /db2u/scripts/include/common_functions.sh && start_wvha_allnodes\"\n
      \   kubectl exec -it -n db2-spm ${CAT_NODE?} -- bash -c \"$cmd\"\n    RC=$?\nfi\nexit
      $RC        \n"
    image: icr.io/obs/hdm/db2u/db2u.tools:11.5.4.0-56-unknown
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: engn-update
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 250Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 200Mi
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 500
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/blumeta0
      name: metavol
    - mountPath: /mnt/blumeta0/configmap/hadr
      name: db2u-release-2-db2u-hadr-config-volume
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: db2u-token-sv5sw
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: db2u-dockercfg-ndhhw
  - name: ibm-registry
  initContainers:
  - args:
    - -cx
    - /tools/post-install/db2u_ready.sh --replicas 1 --template db2u-release-2 --namespace
      db2-spm --dbType db2oltp
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    image: icr.io/obs/hdm/db2u/db2u.tools:11.5.4.0-56-unknown
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: condition-ready
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 250Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 200Mi
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 500
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: db2u-token-sv5sw
      readOnly: true
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -ec
    - |
      DETERMINATION_FILE=/mnt/blumeta0/nodeslist
      CAT_NODE=$(head -1 $DETERMINATION_FILE)
      # After INSTDB job completes, Db2 instance home is persisted on disk. Which is a
      # prerequisite for the VRMF detection code, since it depends on ~/sqllib/.instuse file.
      kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/db2u-release-2-db2u-sqllib-shared-job -n db2-spm
      kubectl exec -it -n db2-spm ${CAT_NODE?} -- bash -c "sudo /db2u/scripts/detect_db2_vrmf_change.sh -file"
    image: icr.io/obs/hdm/db2u/db2u.tools:11.5.4.0-56-unknown
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: detect-vrmf-change
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 500Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 250Mi
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 500
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/blumeta0
      name: metavol
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: db2u-token-sv5sw
      readOnly: true
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Never
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    seLinuxOptions:
      level: s0:c24,c14
  serviceAccount: db2u
  serviceAccountName: db2u
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - name: metavol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: db2u-release-2-db2u-meta-storage
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: db2u-release-2-db2u-hadr-config
    name: db2u-release-2-db2u-hadr-config-volume
  - name: db2u-token-sv5sw
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: db2u-token-sv5sw
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-07-09T12:27:00Z"
    message: '0/5 nodes are available: 5 node(s) didn''t match node selector.'
    reason: Unschedulable
    status: "False"
    type: PodScheduled
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: Burstable
```

and the output to "oc get nodes --show-labels":

```
NAME                                        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION           LABELS
ip-10-0-51-114.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    worker   10d   v1.17.1+912792b   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a,icp4data=icp4data,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-51-114,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,node.openshift.io/os_id=rhcos,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
ip-10-0-52-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master   10d   v1.17.1+912792b   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a,icp4data=icp4data,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-52-157,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,node.openshift.io/os_id=rhcos,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
ip-10-0-56-116.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    worker   10d   v1.17.1+912792b   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a,icp4data=icp4data,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-56-116,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,node.openshift.io/os_id=rhcos,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
ip-10-0-60-205.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master   10d   v1.17.1+912792b   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a,icp4data=icp4data,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-60-205,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,node.openshift.io/os_id=rhcos,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
ip-10-0-63-107.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master   10d   v1.17.1+912792b   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a,icp4data=icp4data,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-63-107,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge,node.openshift.io/os_id=rhcos,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-2,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-2a
```

Comment: You should check what kind of "nodeSelector" is currently set for your Pod. Please add the output of `oc get po -o yaml <name-of-the-pod>` to your question and also provide the output for `oc get nodes --show-labels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pods aren't scheduling because no node label matches what the affinity section of the pod is looking for:

```
nodeSelectorTerms: 
- matchExpressions: 
   - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch 
     operator: In 
     values: 
     - unknown
```

This looks like it's looking for a label `beta.kubernetes.io/arch=unknown`. Assuming that the pods are created by a deployment, a replica set, or even a job, you need to `oc edit` that controller resource and change the nodeSelectorTerms values to `amd64`, and it should meet the conditions for scheduling.

An `oc describe` of your pod should tell you the controller resource, the value for `Controlled By:`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though your solution couldn't solve the problem(as there was a script that was internally changing the label value which was in IBM helm chart) but took me close to finding out the solution (which was modifying the script).

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear you got to the bottom of the issue!